# write the same element in a list into txt file

Tags: python

I have a list in dict which I have extracted the data that I need; 'uni', 'gp', 'fr', 'rn'.

```
uni:1   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:DS
uni:1   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:PP
uni:1   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:LL
uni:2   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:DS
uni:2   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:LL
.
.
.
```

Above is the output that I write in a txt file with code in below:

```
for line in new_l:
    for key,value in line.items():
        if key == 'uni':
            unique.append(value)
        elif key == 'gp':
            pg.append(value)
        elif key == 'fr':
            rf.append(value)
        elif key == 'rn':
            rn.append(value)

with open('sampel1.list',mode='w') as f:
    for unique,gp,fr,rn in zip(uni,gp,fr,rn):
        f.write('uni:{uni}\t,gp:{gp}\t,fr:{fr}\t,rn:{rn}-\n'.format(uni=uni,gp=gp,fr=fr,rn=rn))
```

The expected output that I want is to merge the 'rn' which has different value with each other and same value of 'unique','gp','fr'.

```
unique:1   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:DS+PP+LL
unique:2   gp:CC   fr:c2   rn:DS+LL
```

Comment: I suggest starting by breaking down the problem a bit more.  Forget about writing to a text file for a second.  What you really want to think about is how to merge a table of values keyed on the values of some columns of the table (in this case the triplet of "unique", "gp", and "fr".  I say this because if you phrase your question a little more in terms of data structures you might find an existing solution more easily.  You will need to loop over your dataset and do this merging first.  Then you can worry about things like output.

Comment: Is the text in the very top a list, dataframe, string, or dict?

Comment: @AnnZen it is the output of my my txt file which I iterate thru a list

Comment: Can you post the original text file?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I might do something like this using pure Python.  Note: this particular solution is relying on the fact that Python 3.7 dicts preserve insertion order:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
# This will map the (uni, gp, fr) triplets to the list of merged rn values
merged = defaultdict(list)
for l in new_l:
    # Assuming these keys are always present; if not you will need to check
    # that and skip invalid entries
    key = (l['uni'], l['gp'], l['fr'])
    merged[key].append(l['rn'])

# Now if you wanted to write this to a file, say:
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for (uni, gp, fr), rn in merged.items():
        f.write(f'uni:{uni}\tgp:{gp}\tfr:{fr}\trn:{"+".join(rn)}\n')
```

Note, when I wrote "pure Python" I meant just using the standard library.  In practice I might use Pandas if I'm working with tabular data.

Comment: Also consider using `merged = defaultdict(set)` if you have duplicates you want to merge from the 'rn' field

Answer (score 0):

You need study a little about algoritms and data structure.
In this case you can use the first 3 elements to create a unique hash, and based in this value append or not the last element.

Example:

```
lst = []
lst.append({'uni':1, 'gp':'CC', 'fr':'c2', 'rn':'DS'})
lst.append({'uni':1, 'gp':'CC', 'fr':'c2', 'rn':'PP'})
lst.append({'uni':1, 'gp':'CC', 'fr':'c2', 'rn':'LL'})
lst.append({'uni':2, 'gp':'CC', 'fr':'c2', 'rn':'DS'})
lst.append({'uni':2, 'gp':'CC', 'fr':'c2', 'rn':'PP'})
lst.append({'uni':3, 'gp':'CC', 'fr':'c2', 'rn':'DS'})


hash = {}

for line in lst:
   hashkey = str(line['uni'])+line['gp']+line['fr']
   if hashkey in hash.keys():
      hash[hashkey]['rn']+="+"+line['rn']
   else:
      hash[hashkey]={'uni':line['uni'], 'gp':line['gp'], 'fr':line['fr'], 'rn':line['rn']}

 print(hash)
```

result: **{'1CCc2': {'uni': 1, 'gp': 'CC', 'fr': 'c2', 'rn': 'DS+PP+LL'}, '2CCc2': {'uni': 2, 'gp': 'CC', 'fr': 'c2', 'rn': 'DS+PP'}, '3CCc2': {'uni': 3, 'gp': 'CC', 'fr': 'c2', 'rn':
'DS'}}**

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add how I approach problems like this.  You are grouping by the first 3 fields, so I would place them in a tuple (not a list; the dictionary index must be an immutable object) and use that as an index to a dictionary.  Then, as you read each line from your input file, test if the tuple is already in the dictionary or not. If it is, concatenate to the previous values already saved.

```
myDict = {}

f = open("InputData.txt","r")
for line in f:
    #print( line.strip())
    tup = line.strip().split('\t')
    #print(tup)
    ind = (tup[0],tup[1],tup[2])

    if ind in myDict:
        if tup[3] not in myDict[ind]:
            myDict[ind] = myDict[ind] + "+" + tup[3][3:]
    else:
        myDict[ind] = tup[3][3:]

f.close()
print(myDict)
```

Once the data is in the dictionary object, you can iterate over it and write your output like in the other answers above. (My answer assumes your input text file is tab delimited.)

I find dictionaries very helpful in cases like this.